# split-sequence- delimit sequence by double space

Tags: arrays, input, lisp, sequence

I know how to delimit a string sequence by a space:

```
(defun ff-cols (dir file)
  (with-open-file (ff-cols-str pathname :direction :input)
    (length (split-sequence #\Space (read-line ff-cols-str nil 'eof)))))
```

But how do you delimit a sequence by a double space? Often flat files have 
columns separated by double spaces.

```
(split-sequence "  " "1  2  3  4")
```

returns

```
("1  2  3  4") ;
10
```

Also,

```
(split-sequence #\Space "1  2  3  4")
```

returns

```
("1" "" "2" "" "3" "" "4") ;
10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
(split-sequence-if (lambda (s) (equal s "  ")) "1  2  3  4")
```

Or this:

```
(split-sequence #\Space "1  2  3  4" :remove-empty-subseqs t)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I haven't implemented `split-sequence-if` before, looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

```
(ql:quickload "cl-ppcre")
(cl-ppcre:split "\\s\\s" "One  Two Three  Four   Five")
("One" "Two Three" "Four" " Five")
```

Obviously, whatever you could've learned from other languages which also make use of regular expressions applies.

Comment: Thanks very much, I wasn't aware of the cl-ppcre library- I could also add another split to get rid of single spaces on the outsides of flat file columns.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because your string is not seperated by double spaces

```
(split-sequence "  " "1 2 3 4")
```

try

```
(split-sequence "  " "1  2  3  4")
```

Comment: Sorry I'll correct that now. It still returns the input string.